# How do I go about fixing this window that won't pull shut, either temporarily or permanently? So much cold air is leaking in

Tags: windows, stuck

Album link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehjnV.jpg

By looking at the other windows that function properly this one white lever should cause two little arm thingies to pull the two brown tabs inward and shut the window. The problem is neither or the metal bits inside the frame are doing their job. I sprayed both ports with WD40 and that did not help.

Pushing the window closed from the outside doesn't work either, it just bounces back to the position shown in pics 2 and 3 which lets in so much cold air.

Any ideas how to properly fix this? Or the type of latching mechanism even? Don't even know what to google.

Comment: Can you have one person push it from the outside and the other close the latches?

Comment: So even with the window pressed all the way in to its correct spot from the outside the latches don't close. When I pull the white switch a metal hook is supposed to pull the brown tabs in. The metal hook does not move which is what I'm trying to fix. When pressure is let off the window it bounces back to the partially open position.

Comment: Stop using WD-40. On anything.  It melts/damages glue and plastic.   Have you tried clearing the leaves and crud out of the operating travel range of the window?

Comment: With someone pressing lightly from the outside can you crank the window closed a bit more.

Comment: Someone edited my question and removed the album for some reason. The window closes all the way. The issue is the locking mechanism. This problem window closes the right amount as every other working window. The issue is the locking mechanism that I don't know how to fix since it's just some bits of metal in the wood frame that are seemingly inaccessible via fingers.

Comment: i would stuff it with foam or paper-mache until i could get it fixed right, leaks are expensive.

Comment: Typical casement windows will close more then that if the locking mechanism does not block it. Might be backwards to that of the other windows. Will it close more if the lever is in the "locked" position?

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at another window. Move the lever to get an idea what should be happening. From the outside, with the window open, look for a removable plate that covers the mechanism. Open a good one to see how it works, then open the bad one to see what is not working. If it can't be fixed easily, remove the whole mechanism and go to local window suppliers. It should be removeable. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have windows like yours. So, open the window wide and go outside a make sure that the screws that connect the hinge mechanism and the hinges, both on the bottom and the top, are screwed all the way in (tight). If they are loose they can jamb on the bottom frame. Also, check the closing mechanism as "John Canon" suggested. Make sure the mechanism is working properly.

Comment: It is the mechanism. The window closes all the way it just won't pull it in shut. My question is how do I go about fixing the mechanism. I don't even know what to search to find pictures of it online. There is just a small little slit on the frame side which houses the metal pieces of the mechanism. Can't really get inside to see what's happening because the slit is so small.